# Object required error in Workbook_Open with For loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

***It's working!! Thanks everyone for the help :D - turns out range was declared and set as "columnnrange" and the for loop was using "columnrange". It's the little things ;) . Appreciate the insight and guidance all!

*Thanks for the help everyone! I've updated the code per the responses. The error definitely comes when the For loop runs - if it is commented out there is no error. I believe the error is with the range "columnrange" object. Thanks!!

I have a simple `Workbook_Open()` routine that opens a UserForm "SelectData" and sets a ComboBox "DisplayData" value. I have a `MsgBox` that confirms the value set in the ComboBox "DisplayData".
Once set, the UserForm "SelectData" is hidden. Then, there is a `"for"` loop to hide all columns where the given cell in range "columnrange" is not equal to the ComboBox value. I'm getting an error "object required" but for the life of me cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. The goal of this spreadsheet is: "on open", allow the user to filter the visible columns on an excel doc exported from a SharePoint list.
Thanks in advance!!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim columnrange As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set columnnrange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr").Range("G1:Z1")

SelectData.Show

MsgBox (SelectData.DisplayData.Value)

For Each cell In columnrange
    If SelectData.DisplayData.Value <> cell Then
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   Else
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   End If
Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: With using breaks; can you give us after which line of the code error appears?

Comment: Try `<>cell` as that is what you are looping, 'each cell in columnrange.cells'- you also want to hide the `cell.entirecolumn.hidden=true`

Comment: As shA.t mentioned. please provide us with the error line. It's much simpler to debug if you know where to look ;)

Comment: Added to above but wanted to list here as well - Thanks everyone for the help :D - turns out range was declared and set as "columnnrange" and the for loop was using "columnrange". It's the little things ;) . Appreciate the insight and guidance all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the loop condition to verify **cell** instead of **columnrange**. Here is a simplified code that should work.

```
For Each cell In columnrange    
    If SelectData.DisplayData.Value <> cell Then
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If    
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be sure the SelectData form is open. Do you have the code behind for the OK or Close button? If you use something like `Me.Close` then you won't have an object. You can, instead, use `Me.Hide`.